# Standard for storing multiple plain-text tables (csv, tsv) in one file?

Tags: database, sqlite, csv, text, standards

I need to store multiple tables (say, CSVs) in one file. **Is there any spec or standard I can follow?**

I tried queries such as "multi-csv standard" and "single file plaintext database" with little to show.

**Who would be responsible for creating such a standard?**

Here is one plausible option:

```
# TABLE colors
name,hex
red,ff0000
blue,0000ff

# TABLE users
id,name,followers
1,bob,5
2,alice,33
```

### Why not a directory of tables?

- An empty directory is not acknowledged by git
- Hassle to send over network in one transaction (tar/untar or zip/unzip)

### See also

- https://github.com/jennybc/sanesheets/issues/3
- https://www.google.com/search?q=Standard+for+storing+multiple+csv+in+one+file
- [CSV Standard - Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662784/csv-standard-multiple-tables)
- the dump format from sqlite is basically a sequence of commands: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database
- https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/

  - https://dev.to/jcolag/recutils-the-plain-text-database-52ma
- https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools#csv
- [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Comment: The sqlite answer to this is "the sqlite database format", not the output of a .dump command.  But the general answer is "it depends", there's no single answer, just like csv files aren't always the best answer to sharing a single table of data.

Comment: Sqlite db files are not plain text tragically. I was searching for some way to escape the "it depends" but it seems I must choose for myself.

Comment: I think there is not a standard for CSV or TSV, these are single table format. Other text formats - as yaml or json - could contains inside multiple tables. But what's your goal?

Comment: And the JSONlines could be a way to do it https://gist.github.com/aborruso/d8b92c7974c3a71e81898787668ac405

Comment: Json may be the best option. You can also make a  row more compact with just `{table: "colors", "row": ["red","ff0000"]}` or even all the rows in one rectangular array